# Why I have an error for row that user need to key in? in asp.net aspx mvc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This is the error that i get [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLOXl.png)
I don't know what is wrong please help me ..
What I notice is that the error start on the line that user need to give input
I am using the asp.net mvc. There is no problem with database connection. When i run the code i get the error like in the picture given. I think i need to do something about the key in data. but i can't find guidelines for this. please help me.

[This is my vb code]

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO

Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Public Class Shortage

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public cn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString
    Dim cs As New SqlConnection(cn)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Chart1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub preparedby_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles preparedby.Click
        cs.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_shortage VALUES ('" & model.SelectedIndex.ToString() &
                "','" & [Variant].SelectedIndex.ToString() & "','" & Request.Form("partno") &
                "','" & Request.Form("name") & "' ,'" & Request.Form("tarikh") & "','" & Request.Form("partname") & "',
                '" & Request.Form("qty") & "','" & Request.Form("pcno") & "','" & Request.Form("partrepair") & "', '" & Request.Form("lotno") & "',
                '" & Request.Form("pnr") & "','" & Request.Form("caseno") & "','" & Request.Form("source") & "',
                '" & cnl.SelectedIndex.ToString() & "','" & Request.Form("urgently") & "','" & Request.Form("qtys") & "',
                '" & Request.Form("img1") & "','" & Request.Form("img2") & "','" & Request.Form("img3") & "',
                '" & Request.Form("img4") & "','" & Request.Form("img5") & "','" & Request.Form("img6") & "',
                '" & Request.Form("img7") & "','" & Request.Form("img8") & "')" 'STORE NEW USER INFO TO DATABASE
        cmd.Connection = cs
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cs.Close()

        Dim message As String = "Successfully Inserted" 'NOTIFY USER THAT RECORD HAS BEEN SUCCESFULLY INSERTED
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
        sb.Append("alert('")
        sb.Append(message)
        sb.Append("')};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The error states that you can't have an input tag inside a table header. about your code. Please read as soon as possible why writing sql queries in that way is a recipe for disasters. Search about Sql Injection

Comment: I already change to table data but still got the same error

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<input type="text">` in your line 189?

Comment: Or change the `<th>` in the probably correct `<td>`

Comment: I done both of that but still the same problem. This require user input does it need to add any script or what ?

Comment: What about adding a space between `rowspan` and `colspan` tags?

Comment: Obligatory [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) reference. Please use parameterized queries, specifically [SqlParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) in this case.